# Shared volume between Docker containers with python code

Tags: python, docker, volume

Maybe i'm going at it wrong, but i can't seem to get a shared volume working between two docker containers running custom python code.

I'm using the following docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "2"

services:
    rabbitmq:
        image: username/rabbitmq
        ports:
            - 15672:15672
            - 5672:5672
    producer:
        image: username/producer
        depends_on:
            - rabbitmq
        volumes:
            - pdffolder:/temp
    consumer:
        image: username/consumer
        depends_on:
            - producer
        volumes:
            - pdffolder:/temp
volumes:
    pdffolder:
```

The idea is that the producer service polls an exchange server for information and a pdf-file. The consumer service then has to send this information and pdf-file elsewhere. During this action I have to store the pdf locally temporally.

I access the volumes from the custom python-code like this:

producer

```
# attachment = object I get when requesting attachments from an exchange server

# path to pdf to be saved
pdf_path = os.path.join("temp", attachment.name)

with open(pdf_path, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(attachment.content)

# now in this container, /temp/attachment.pdf exists. I then send this path in a message to the consumer (along with other information)
```

consumer

```
# consumer tries to find path created by producer (/temp/attachment.pdf) via
pdf_path = os.path.join("temp", "attachment.pdf")
```

Via the command line i can see that the producer-container is writing the files to temp/attachment.pdf like expected. The consumer-container however sees no files (resulting in errors).

Btw, I am running the containers on docker for windows

Comment: The `pfdfolder` in your service definition doesn't match `pdffolder` in the top-level volumes block; it looks like that should [produce a startup error](https://github.com/docker/compose/blob/master/compose/config/validation.py#L107).  The paths you provide also look suspicious (forward vs. back slash, relative vs. absolute path).  Can you provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: I changed the original question. There were indeed some problems in the spelling of 'pdffolder'. I fixed that. I also changed the way that the paths are defined in the python code. I'm used to developing on windows and realised that defining paths on linux is done differently. Just to be sure, I used os.path.join. I'm still facing the problem that the consumer container can't find the file that was saved to the shared volume.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured out what was wrong. I used the following in both the Dockerfiles for the producer and consumer:

```
FROM python:3.7-slim
WORKDIR /main
ADD . /main
RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r requirements.txt
CMD ["python", "-u", "main.py"]
```

Because I moved the python code to the /main folder in both containers, the temp folder created later (via docker-compose) was to be found at /main/temp, and not just /temp. A little bit weird because the main.py should be at the same level as /temp, but hey it works. I got it working with the following docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "2"

services:
    rabbitmq:
        image: username/rabbitmq
        ports:
            - 15672:15672
            - 5672:5672
    producer:
        image: username/producer
        depends_on:
            - rabbitmq
        volumes:
            - pdffolder:/main/temp
    consumer:
        image: username/consumer
        depends_on:
            - producer
        volumes:
            - pdffolder:/main/temp
volumes:
    pdffolder:
```

So i guess the steps to debugging this are:

- Check the spelling of all mentions of volumes in the docker-compose.yml file
- Check the way paths are being built/referenced in the python code (Linux uses a different format to windows)
- Check if the paths that have to be accessed from the python code actually exist